# How to use filter in controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a scope variable called "sampledata" in controller.
I am displaying data in view using filters on the same:-

```
<div ng-repeat="value in sampledata|orderBy:sortType | filter:   {label:filter_one} | filter: {name_filter: filterName}">
</div>
```

I want to filter the data in the same way in controller as well. How can i do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this by inject $filter dependency in controller function

```
function DoFilter() {
    var orderedBy = $filter('orderBy')($scope.sampledata, $scope.sortType);
    returned $filter('filter')(orderedBy,{label: $scope.filter_one, name_filter: $scope.filterName})
}
```

Comment: what is sortBy variable here?

Comment: My bad, it should be `sortType`